# How to group rules together in the UI?

Tags: rules, 7

My website has a lot of rules and it's becoming hard to find a specific one fast via the UI. I know I can filter them, but I almost never use that feature. Is there a way to group rules with the same tag together in an expandable block or something? That would make life a lot easier. (Maybe I should post this as a feature request on the Rules' issue queue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned, Rules provides a tagging feature to tag / label rules. You then apply a filter to view that set of Rules only.

Any other grouping of Rules would require custom coding to retheme / template the layout of that page.